# Can sharing docker info compromise security?

Tags: docker

Running `docker info` gives a result such as this:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: alphanumeric number (expected: alphanumeric no.)
runc version: N/A (expected: alphanumeric no. )
init version: v0.18.0 (expected: alphanumeric number)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-1-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.659GiB
Name: debian
ID: 4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name:4name
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

The unique ID's perhaps are containerid version, runc version and ID version. If somebody comes to know of these details, could there be problems?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you wouldn't want to share any piece of enumeration info to anyone..
However if you need to share this with a vendor, I don't see a problem sharing this specific log file.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, there's no passwords or keys that could be used to log in for example. It would be useful for someone looking to crack your system as it gives them a lot of handy information, for example:

- Operating system type
- OS kernel version
- Security options
- Plugins

These would remove a lot of the guesswork, so you'd want to limit who would have access to this report to those that need it.